# Why is it ok to let a number in an inequality identity be a variable and differentiate with respect it to prove the identity?

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Prove that$$\frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}\geq ab$$
>   where $$ \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} =1$$ and 
>   $a,b,p,q\in\mathbb{R}^+$

**Solution.** Let $x=a$, and define
$$f(x) =\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}-xb$$

Then we take the derivative of this function, proving that this has a minimum stationary point that lies above $x$ axis. Therefore $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

> Can someone tell me why this works, letting $a$ become a variable. Why isn't it necessary to let $a$, $b$, $p$, $q$ all be variables and do partial derivatives?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products

Comment: What is an "inequality identity"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol $a$ in the equation $\frac{a^p}{b} + \frac{b^q}{q} \ge ab$, as well as the symbols $b,p,q$, are indeed all variables.

However, variables can be treated differently in logical formulas. For example, a quantified variable becomes what we call a *bound variable*. Formally that's what is happening in this problem, although the quantifiers have been suppressed. A better way to word things would be like this:

> For every $b,p,q > 0$, consider the function $f(x) = \frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{b^q}{q} - xb$.

Notice what has happened: I've stuck a universal quantifier in front of $b,p,q$, thereby making them bound variables, so they are now essentially constants in the formula for the function $f$. And now I'm free to apply the laws of calculus in which $b,p,q$ are indeed constants.

Also, the reason that $x$ was substituted in place of $a$ is simply because of our human mathematical conventions: it is more common for $a$ to be a constant and for $x$ to be a variable, so if I want to leave $a$ as a *free variable* it is easier on my comprehension to replace it by $x$.